# Shifting items on a page when collosion occurs

Tags: html, css

I think you need to see the result in order to understand my question.

```css
.boxAAA {
  border: 4px solid #548235;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  margin: auto;
  width: 75%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

#boxBBB {
  border: 2px solid #002060;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  padding: 10px;
  min-width: 250px;
  margin-right: 290px;
}

#boxCCC {
  float: right;
  border: 2px solid #002060;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxAAA">
  <h2>AAA</h2>
</div>

</br>

<div id="boxCCC">
  <h3>CCC</h3>The quick brown fox
</div>

<div id="boxBBB">
  <h3>BBB</h3>
  </br>
  <img src="xxxxxxxxxxxxx.png">
  </br>
  The quick brown fox
  </br>
</div>

</br>
</br>

<div style="padding: 10px; border:2px solid #002060; background-color:#F2F2F2; color:black;">
  <h3>DDD</h3>
  <p>The quick brown fox
</div>

</br>
```

If you run the script, you will see that boxCCC has a fixed width when the page size changes. However if the page size is too small, it will overlap with boxBBB. What I would like is, when the two boxes collide, is for boxCCC to be placed below boxBBB. Then the page will look like this:

```
[AAA]  
[BBB]  
[CCC]  
[DDD]
```

What I would like is for boxBBB and boxCCC to be side-by-side, unless the page is too small and they collide. In this event, I would like boxCCC to sit below boxBBB.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

**Measure** the width, you need, and set a **media** **query** with this width

```
@media screen and (max-width: measured width) {}
```

Don't use `<br>` in this case. Do it with CSS (margin, padding, ...)

Use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

**Completely changed layout**

```css
.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

div[class^="box-"] {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.box-a {
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto !important;
}

.box-b {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0.7;
  -ms-flex: 0.7;
  flex: 0.7;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.box-c {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0.3;
  -ms-flex: 0.3;
  flex: 0.3;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .wrapper {
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .box-a {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .box-b {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box-a">
  Box A
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box-b">Box B</div>
  <div class="box-c">Box C</div>
</div>
<div class="box-d">Box D</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. When I run this in w3schools, it works as desired.

However I should have said that this is for my Wordpress page. It seems there is something missing because there it only presents the box titles without any boxes. 

I've tried adding the 'style' tags, but I can't get it working. Which tags am I missing?

Comment: The answer is edited. Added prefixes for all browser and `border: 1px solid black`. I don't know how to include a CSS file in wordpress. http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-easily-add-custom-css-to-your-wordpress-site/

Comment: For anyone else reading this, would you be able to change the code (first section only) and remove line spaces? I found out that Wordpress has a quirk where line spaces are filled with <p>. That's why the code wasn't working properly.